# What is sources.list?

Tags: linux, files, apt, repository

I know `sources.list` is a file that contains a list of HTTP links pointing to some software downloads.

I would like to know more detailed explanations and various conventions followed in the `sources.list` file.

Answer (score 7):

You can also find complete information at the man page for that file:

`man sources.list`

Answer (score 4):

You can find more information in Debian Wiki, for example:

[Debian Wiki - SourcesList](http://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList)